# How to configure logging with mongodb java driver and wildfly

Tags: java, mongodb, wildfly

My setup is a web application ( war )  built with java 8 and running using wildfly 17.0.1

Problem: during development ( but also in production on a file logger ) I need to print out application's queries. This for relational database (for example Postgres ) using jpa is simple: go to persistenc.xml and set to true following lines:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

with mongodb I'm not able to found a similar configuration or options, so I'm not able to log every query to mondob java driver is doing.

For clarification:

- logger : org.jboss.logging.Logger
- slf4j is in the classpath (  org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 as gradle transitive dependency )
- I've tried to configure inside wildfly console application a logger on package org.mongodb.driver , but is not working on any level

Comment: MongoDB Java driver [logging reference](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/reference/logging/).

Comment: I've read it, but what I have to do exactly ? In my setup in particular

Comment: To start with nothing, I think. Why not deploy a test application with some MongoDB Java code and see if the logs have the required details.